# How do I convert a 13 digit number into a date without showing the time using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

So I'm trying to convert the following 13 digit to a readable date in the format of: m/dd/yyyy but the year is outputting incorrectly. I get the following output 6/3/48790. I would also like to only show the Month year and date, not the time.

My example code is

```js
var data = {
  "date_created": "1477509774000"
};
var date = new Date(parseInt(data.date_created, 10) * 1000);
// example representations
alert(date);
alert(date.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: `new Date(+data.date_created)`.

Comment: you don't need to multiply by 1000 again, it looks like the date.date_created has already been multiplied

Comment: I'd recommended spending more time reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and less time here. I should probably do the latter as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var data = {"date_created":"1477509774000"};
var date = new Date(parseInt(data.date_created));

//Create your custom format
var fdate = (date.getMonth() + 1)+'/'+ date.getDate()  +'/'+date.getFullYear()
alert(fdate);

// example representations
alert(date);
alert(date.toDateString());
```

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. `date.getMonth()` should be `(date.getMonth() + 1)`.

Comment: Thanks @RobG , I've changed my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So I got this 10 digits of time which it should be 13 digits so here is my solution

```
   const handleDate = (item) =>{
     let st = item.toString()
     let s = `${st}000`
     let n = parseInt(s)
     let date = new Date(parseInt(n))
      return (date.getMonth() + 1)+'/'+ date.getDate()  +'/'+date.getFullYear()   
   }
```